# Function to find if a point lies on a line given two points in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def isOnLine(xCord1, yCord1, xCord2, yCord2, xCord3, yCord3):
    mSlope = (yCord2 - yCord1) / (xCord2 - xCord1)
    return mSlope
lineEquation = y - yCord1 = mSlope * (x - xCord1)
```

What I need is a function that when given three coordinates, will determine a line from the first two coordinates and then take the third coordinate and see if it falls on the line, returning a bool indicating  true if the coordinate does fall on the line or a false if the coordinate does not fall on the line.
So far all I have is a function finding the slope of a line from the first two coordinates given. I know I can take the slope and the first two coordinates and find the equation of the line and then using the equation of the line take the third coordinate and see if it lies on the line. However I can't use that equation because y and x have no assigned value, is there another way I can calculate this?

Comment: Why don't you compute the slope between coordinate 2 and coordinate 3 and see if it matches the slope you computed for coordinates 1 and 2? The line equation itself with the variables doesn't matter. All you should care about is the slopes.

Answer (score 0):

You are close to a theoretically correct function, that works with perfect (error free) data.

```
def is_on_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    return y3 - y1 == slope * (x3 - x1)

print(is_on_line(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2))
# True
```

Lurkers suggestion is to turn the equality test above into the equivalent

```
(y3 - y1) / (x3 - x1) == slope
```

However, for arbitrary floating point numbers, exact equality for whatever criterion you use is essentially impossible.  So you must test 'close enough'.  You could either subtract slope and test that the difference is close enough to 0.  Or you could divide by slope and test close enough to 1.  What I would do is look up the formula for the perpendicular distance between a point and a line and test that distance for 'close enough' to 0.

Comment: Hi, why this does not work for me? print(is_on_line(168.0451,-44.3994,168.0480,-44.3987,168.0466,-44.3990)) is returning false. Ideally it should return true.

Comment: The 2 expressions compared in the return statement differ by 3.793103447704752e-05.  As I said, is_on_line is for the ideal case of infinite precision, and practical functions need to test 'close enough', as determined by the user.